# Spring Data Mongodb 2.0.2 CustomConversions NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I want to use Spring Data Mongodb.
the problem is that when I change the Spring Data Mongodb version from 1.10.9.RELEASE to 2.0.2.RELEASE a problem shows up in compile time:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/convert/CustomConversions
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:697)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1484)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:425)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:395)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$BeanPostProcessorsRegistrar.registerSyntheticBeanIfMissing(EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.java:148) .....
```

this problem is not showing up when using Spring Data Mongodb 1.x.y.
currently I've bootstrapped the project with spring boot 1.5.9.RELEASE.

Comment: Same problem here but with spring-data-cassandra package. Any luck so far?

Comment: Faced the same issue

Comment: Not yet, I've didn't have enough time to investigate this issue, so i falled back to spring-data-mongodb 1.10.10 for now

Comment: They released 2.0.3 as current release. maybe that will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that Spring Data 2.x is not compatible with Spring Boot 1.x. according to This question:

[NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSource.getAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47907236/nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-data-repository-config-repositoryconfigur)

so you could not use Spring data Mongodb 2.x or Spring Data Neo4J 5.x without upgrading to Spring boot 2